# Select data using WHERE condition on XML data column in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that lists some user details.

| ID | GUID | Username | Password | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a2a8s7d4d | xswe | xxxxxx | XML |
| 2 | aer335mla | user | xxxxxx | XML |

The **Data** column contains data using XML. Below is a sample from the table.

```
<UserInfo xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ComponentFramework">
<ActiveDirectoryUser>false</ActiveDirectoryUser>
<CanUpdateMasterData>false</CanUpdateMasterData>
<CanUploadFiles>false</CanUploadFiles>
<ChangePassword>false</ChangePassword>
<CustomDataPageSize>false</CustomDataPageSize>
<CustomMasterDataPageSize>false</CustomMasterDataPageSize>
<DataPageSize>100</DataPageSize>
<Disabled>true</Disabled>
<Displayname>Pål</Displayname>
<Email i:nil="true" />
<EnforcePasswordPolicy>false</EnforcePasswordPolicy>
<EnvironmentIdList xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />
<GUID i:nil="true" />
<GeoLocation>
    <City i:nil="true" />
    <Country i:nil="true" />
    <CountryCode i:nil="true" />
    <Ip i:nil="true" />
    <Isp i:nil="true" />
    <Lat>0</Lat>
    <Lon>0</Lon>
    <Org i:nil="true" />
    <Query i:nil="true" />
    <Region i:nil="true" />
    <RegionName i:nil="true" />
    <Status i:nil="true" />
    <Timezone i:nil="true" />
    <Zip i:nil="true" />
</GeoLocation>
<GroupIdList xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />
<HttpLink i:nil="true" />
<JobIdList xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />
<LastLoggedIn>2015-06-11T19:04:44.6407074+05:30</LastLoggedIn>
<MasterDataPageSize>1000</MasterDataPageSize>
<ModifyImages>false</ModifyImages>
<QualityControl>false</QualityControl>
<QualityControlGroupId i:nil="true" />
<Review>false</Review>
<ReviewGroupId i:nil="true" />
<SecurityToken i:nil="true" />
<ShowTrackerPage>false</ShowTrackerPage>
<StatIdList xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />
<Username>&lt;new user&gt;</Username>
<Usertype>Power</Usertype>
</UserInfo>
```

I'm trying to match users that have their accounts disabled. Using the below sql query.

`select * from [ATC_Config].[dbo].[Users] where [ATC_Config].[dbo].[Users].[Data].value('/UserInfo/Disabled[1]','nvarchar(MAX)') = 'true'`

But SSMS is giving me an error `Cannot call methods on nvarchar(max)` and highlight my column which **Data**. I tried few suggestions in SO and in MSDN but nothing helped. Can someone show me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error is telling you the problem; clearly you column `Data` isn't the `xml` data type. If it's storing XML, it should be the `xml` data type, and as you've found out, you can't use XQuery methods on an `nvarchar` column.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for the comment. I have to convert this column to `XML` first then use the query to search. This is not my DB inherited this. Thanks again.

Comment: You could try casting to `VARCHAR(4000)`

Comment: @Kendle will try that as well. Thank you.

Comment: Your XML sample has a default namespace defined. You'll need to specify that either inside your value query or using `with xmlnamespaces`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning your mean this right `xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`. I did but still got an error after that I decided to post here.

Comment: Nope, I mean the default namespace for ComponentFramework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your sample XML contains a default namespace definition you'll need to declare that in your `value` XQuery or via `with xmlnamespaces`.

Here's how you can do that with `value`...

```sql
select *
from dbo.Users
where cast(Data as xml).value(N'
  declare default element namespace "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ComponentFramework";
  (/UserInfo/Disabled)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') = N'true';
```

Or by using `with xmlnamespaces`:

```sql
with xmlnamespaces(default N'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ComponentFramework')
select *
from dbo.Users
where cast(Data as xml).value(N'(/UserInfo/Disabled)[1]', N'nvarchar(max)') = N'true';
```

Comment: Thank you this worked and learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the namespace, and you need to cast the value to `xml`. This is easier if you use `with` because it applies to the whole query.

A slightly more efficient version of [@AlwaysLearning's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71438271/14868997) is to use `exist` and `/text()`

```sql
with xmlnamespaces (
    default N'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ComponentFramework'
)
select *
from dbo.Users u
where cast(u.Data as xml).exist(N'/UserInfo/Disabled[text() = "true"]') = 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=717d9370ca364caac340f8b6c79e7dd4)

I strongly suggest you store the `Data` column as `xml` in the first place, as casting is inefficient.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion but this is database is part of a live production system. So kind of having second thoughts of converting the data type. Because I inherited the entire system from the last guy. I just don't want to mess with the live system but have to clean the unwanted users.

Comment: Both answers are right. If I could mark both as right I would have but marked @AlwaysLearning as the answer and gave you an upvote.